# How to display Multi Picklist values in new lines instead of separated by a semi colon in Salesforce

Tags: formula, process-builder, multi-select

I have a multi picklist field called 'Rejection_Reasons__c' which is dependent on case status. When ever case status='Pending' or 'Rejected', the 'Rejection_Reasons__c' are set by user. As these values keep changing, I am using a process builder to store these values in a new text field 'reasons__c' (Text field) on a child object of case. 
I am assigning reasons__c = Rejection_Reasons__c in the process builder every time the status is changed to 'Pending' or 'Rejected'.

The values are stored as:
Contact person missing;Offer/Contract missing;Configurator missing

Is there a way I can display these values in a new Line instead of semi-colon ';'.

Example:
Contact person missing -newline-
Offer/Contract missing -newline-
Configurator missing

I am looking for a configuration way, without having to use vf/code.

Comment: Get the field value in Apex `split` with '__;__' and the loop through the `list` you will get as a result of `split` function call.

Comment: Is there any way we can use a formula and do it? [We are trying to avoid VF and Apex]

Answer (score 1):

You can use BR() function, this is generally used to insert new line

```
IF(INCLUDES( Rejection_Reasons__c , " Contact person missing"), " Contact person missing", NULL)  + BR() +
```

IF(INCLUDES( Rejection_Reasons__c , "Offer/Contract missing"), "Offer/Contract missing", NULL)  + BR() + 
IF(INCLUDES( Rejection_Reasons__c , "Configurator missing"), "Configurator missing", NULL)

Thank you,
Amol Salve
Salesforce Developer

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you are using the 'reasons__c' field to continually append reason history as 'Rejection_Reasons__c' keeps being updated? If this is the case, you could use a regular workflow (rather than process builder) checking for the case status changes and use a formula like:

```
IF(INCLUDES(Rejection_Reasons__c, "Contact person missing"), "Contact person missing" + BR() , NULL) 
&
IF(INCLUDES(Rejection_Reasons__c, "Offer/Contract missing"), "Offer/Contract missing" + BR() , NULL)
&
IF(INCLUDES(Rejection_Reasons__c, "Configurator missing"), "Configurator missing" + BR() , NULL)
&
PRIORVALUE(reasons__c)
```

I haven't tested that formula above but it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to update child record's field i.e. `Reasons__c` from Case object, you chose the right approach of using a process builder.

Process builder should be invoked whenever a case is created or updated.

Formula for `Reason__c` field update should be something  like this

```
IF(INCLUDES(Case.Rejection_Reasons__c, "Contact person missing"), "Contact person missing" + BR() , NULL) & IF(INCLUDES(Case.Rejection_Reasons__c, "Offer/Contract missing"), "Offer/Contract missing" + BR() , NULL) & IF(INCLUDES(Case.Rejection_Reasons__c, "Configurator missing"), "Configurator missing" + BR() , NULL)
```

You can add remaining picklist values to the formula if needed.